# sort array alphabetically

Tags: iphone, arrays, sorting, tableview

I have a json Database with a lot of different data. 
I save this data in a array and now i want to sort this alphabetically.
can somebody help me how i can do this?

Comment: you can try `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:]`

Comment: Do you want Xcode to sort the array for you? (Because it won't.) Your best bet is trying to sort an array yourself using its methods. (Hint: this question has **nothing** to do with Xcode.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Just edit the tags and move on then; this happens multiple times per day...

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Attribute Name" ascending:NO];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
  [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```